# How to decode my tiff pictures to input tensorflow using pipline?

Tags: batch-file, input, tensorflow, decode, tiff

I am trying to train a neural network using my own tiff pictures with tensorflow pipline. Here is the problem: tensorflow only has 4 kinds of pictures which can be decoded（decode_jpeg, decode_bmp, decode_gif, decode_png）, there is no way to decode tiff pictures. So, how can i decode my tiff pictures to use tensorflow pipline to input my own data? or how can i decode my tiff pictures to use batch?

Comment: or how can i input my tiff pictures to train?  It is also fine using tf.placeholder or tf.variables.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  To get the best results, it is helpful to read through the hints on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  As is, your question is relatively broad and is not ideal for the question and answer format of this site.

Comment: You could use the freely available **ImageMagick** to convert your TIFFs to PNG or JPEG images. So, if you wanted to convert a whole directory of TIFFs into JPEGs, you could run `mogrify -format PNG *.TIFF`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985509/tensorflow-machine-learning-no-decoder-for-tiff-images

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  I will try it.

Comment: I convert my tiff pictures to bin file, then, use nummpy.array to convert it to array. so tensorflow could use the array to train in TFrecords. And it`s worked. But here comes a new question, the loss function is not convergent. I don`t know the problem is out of the initializers of weights and biases, or out of the local minima?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/experimental/image/decode_tiff).

```
tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(
    contents, index=0, name=None
)
```

> **contents:**  A Tensor of type string. 0-D. The TIFF-encoded image.
>
> **index:** A Tensor of type int64. 0-D. The 0-based index of the frame inside TIFF-encoded image.
>
> **name:**  A name for the operation (optional).

Comment: Sadly, this can not handle tiff stacks.